# Adding Wizz Flex after purchase

Tags: air-travel, bookings, wizz-air

I booked a ticket yesterday evening through Wizz, as a Wizz Club member, but forgot to click Wizz Flex. I desperately need to purchase this service for my booking. I tried to buy it again online after my booking was confirmed but it was not possible. My flight is from Tirana TIA to London Luton LTN.

Which kind of solution you have in such a case, please?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please note that our contributors are volunteers and cannot help you directly; as such I have removed some of the personal information you included in the original post. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. That said, have you tried calling Wizz Air to see if they will accommodate you?\

Comment: If you are still within a 24 window after booking, you may be able to cancel for free and simply rebook

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you're out of luck. The [information page about WIZZ Flex](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/wizz-services/wizz-flex) does not list any other way of purchasing it apart from when making a booking. Given the nature of WIZZ Flex, it doesn't make much sense to allow adding it later. If that was possible, anyone could avoid paying cancellation/change fees or the Wizz Flex fee by only buying WIZZ Flex when they actually needed to cancel/change.

You can try [calling WIZZ Air](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/contact/contact-us) and asking them if they can add WIZZ Flex to your booking, but as I said, your chance of success is likely minimal.